# CopyResource from one D3D11 device to another

Tags: c++, textures, direct3d, direct3d11

I can copy the content from a D3D11 texture to another one with `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource`. The method belongs to the immediate context of a specific device, so I cannot copy a texture from one device to another one (I have tried it - it explodes as expected saying

> "D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource: First parameter
>   does not match device. [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #13:
>   CORRUPTED_PARAMETER1]"

).

Is there any D3D11 built-in means for doing this or must I download the data via a staging texture and upload it to the other device?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to explicitly lock and copy yourself.  This also makes sense because different D3D devices can actually be different hardware devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy a resource from one device to another, you need to use DXGI Shared Surfaces. See [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554.aspx).

Remember that in the general case, the devices may not have any physical memory or hardware in common.

Comment: Do you know whether a shared Surface is (significantly) faster than doing the copy by yourself? I would assume that only the CPU overhead could be less, because the driver could optimise this, but copying via PCIe can never be avoided.

Comment: I think there might be some performance benefit if it's actually on the same physical device, but it's never going to be particularly 'fast' to do this